# What is golang.org/x namespace?

Tags: go, go-modules

I know to import a package, we could use

```golang
import (
        "golang.org/x/text"
)
```

I have a question about the `golang.org/x`? Is this the namespace for all standard libraries to live? How does this namespace play in the go ecosystem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From [the mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/u/1/g/golang-nuts/c/eD8dh3T9yyA/m/l5Ail-xfMiAJ), it looks like the import path, `golang.org/x`, was introduced for [sub-repositories packages](https://golang.org/pkg/#subrepo) in Go 1.4:

> These packages are part of the Go Project but outside the main Go tree. They are developed under looser compatibility requirements than the Go core. Install them with "go get".

The x means eXternal to standard libraries.

So `golang.org/x` is the import path for sub-repositories packages.

- `import "net/http"` (Standard Library)
- `import "golang.org/x/text"` (Library in sub-repository)